# Future and asynchronism

Tags: android, asynchronous, futuretask, esri-arc-engine

I use a extern api (ESRI API for Android) where I have a loop for which me return a class Future

```
...
for (Layer layer : layers) {

// ListenableFuture extends Future<V>
final ListenableFuture<FeatureQueryResult> future= gdbFeatureTable.queryFeaturesAsync(query);

future.addDoneListener(() -> {
                try {
                    FeatureQueryResult result = future.get();
...
}
```

OR

```
try {
                FeatureQueryResult result = future.get();


    }
    ...
```

Is it possible to launch all queryFeaturesAsync and obtain the global result (result1 + result2 + etc..) with asynchronously after the loop for ?
What's the best way ? promises? ThreadPoolExecutor ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think method `queryFeaturesAsync()` inside already uses `ThreadPoolService`, and using `ThreadPoolService` to retreive result from another `ThreadPoolService` is overkill, IMHO.

I would recomend you to use `AsyncTask` becuse it is native Android SDK tool and very simple to use:

```
AsyncTask<ListenableFuture<FeatureQueryResult>, Integer, List<FeatureQueryResult>> task =
        new AsyncTask<ListenableFuture<FeatureQueryResult>, Integer, List<FeatureQueryResult>>() {
    @Override
    protected List<FeatureQueryResult> doInBackground(ListenableFuture<FeatureQueryResult>[] futures) {
        int counter = 0;
        List<FeatureQueryResult> results = new ArrayList<>();
        for (ListenableFuture<FeatureQueryResult> future : futures) {
            try {
                results.add(future.get());
                publishProgress(++counter); // Optional feature
            } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                Log.w("Huh?", "Interrupted!");
            }
        }
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        notifyMainThreadAboutProgress(values[0]); // Optional feature
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<FeatureQueryResult> featureQueryResults) {
        doSomethingWithResultsInMainThread(featureQueryResults);
    }
};

ListenableFuture<FeatureQueryResult> future1 = gdbFeatureTable.queryFeaturesAsync(query);
ListenableFuture<FeatureQueryResult> future2 = gdbFeatureTable.queryFeaturesAsync(another_query);
ListenableFuture<FeatureQueryResult> future3 = gdbFeatureTable.queryFeaturesAsync(yet_another_query);

task.execute(future1, future2, future3);
```

I made `AsyncTask` as an anonymous class for shortening of example. On production it must be static class.

Comment: ok as that  identifyTask.execute(futures.toArray(new ListenableFuture[futures.size()]));

Comment: may be I work with CompletableFuture 
What do you think ?

Comment: My example doesn't uses capabilities of `ListenableFuture` such as `onDone` callback, but only method `get()` from `Future` interface and I think that `CompletableFuture` also implements it as well.

Comment: My sample code with CompletableFuture below ... What do you think ?

Comment: My sample code with CompletableFuture below ... What do you think ?

Answer (score 0):

If I use CompletableFuture is it the best way ?
I don't understand all ...

```
List<CompletableFuture<FeatureQueryResult>> futures = new ArrayList<>();                
for (Layer layer : layers) {
    FeatureTable gdbFeatureTable = ((FeatureLayer) layer).getFeatureTable();
    CompletableFuture<FeatureQueryResult>  completableFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
    ListenableFuture<FeatureQueryResult> future = gdbFeatureTable.queryFeaturesAsync(query);
    future.addDoneListener(() -> {
                        FeatureQueryResult result = future.get();
                        completableFuture.complete(result);
    }
    futures.add(future);
}
CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[futures.size()]));
```

Do you have a another solution with completablefuture ?

Thanks for your reponse

Comment: Sorry, I've never used `CompletableFuture` before and can not help here. Your example looks too complex for its purpose. I think, you should not stick to the `Future` type. It's just a way to deliver results from one thread to another one and that's it. There are many another ways to syncronize several async tasks together. For instance you can also use `CountDownLatch`.